# Is it natural to say "please play with your Lego in one place, don't play a bit here a bit there as you may lose your bricks"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

I came up with this structure "**to play a bit here a bit there**"

I am not sure if it is what native speakers often say.

Also, Is it natural to say "**please play with your Lego in one place, don't play a bit here a bit there as you may lose your bricks**"?

Comment: An itinerant minstrel (the medieval variety) might play a little bit here, a little bit there........................  "Please play with your Lego in one place, don't play here and there as you may lose your bricks"?

Comment: @BruceMurray, nice, but can I say "...don't play here a bit and there a bit..."?

Comment: You can say it but it's more idiomatic to say: "Don't play a bit here and bit there..........."